# How to upgrade android project from API 18 to 21

Tags: android, api, upgrade

I have a running project in API 18. I want to upgrade it to 21. Is there any specific procedure to upgrade it? Please let me know the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the target SDK?

Go to your project's properties (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>), click android and select the SDK you want to use (preferably the latest one)

You can also specify the minimum SDK  in your `android manifest`. For example, if you set 11 to minimum SDK, phones with API < 11 will not be able to use your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upgrade it from Project Properties.

**Right click on your project-> Go to Properties-> Select Android Version whatever you want-> Click ok.**

You can also do it in Android Manifest.xml file. You can give min and max SDK version in it like below:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8" //Min here is 8 means android 2.2
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```